# TypeScript constructor - ambient contexts error

Tags: syntax, typescript

How do I create a constructor in TypeScript?

Looked at a bunch of guides, but the syntax must've changed. Here's my latest attempt:

#### car.d.ts

```
declare class Car {
    constructor(public engine: string) {
        this.engine = engine + "foo";
    }
}
```

### Error:

> An implementation cannot be called in ambient contexts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By using `declare` you're defining a class type. The type is only defined, and shouldn't have an implementation, so `declare` needs to be removed. Then it compiles fine.

```
class Car {
    constructor(public engine: string) {
        this.engine = engine + "foo";
    }
}
```

However that code compiles to:

```
var Car = (function () {
    function Car(engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
        this.engine = engine + "foo";
    }
    return Car;
})();
```

which sets the `engine` property twice.

That probably wasn't what you intended, so the `engine` property should be defined on the class, not the constructor.

```
class Car {

    public engine: string;

    constructor(engine: string) {
        this.engine = engine + "foo";
    }
}
```

Edit:

The error you received about needing `declare` was due to you using the `.d.ts` extension for definition files. The extension should be just `.ts` if you want the file to compile to JavaScript.

Edit 2:

```
declare class Car {

    public engine;

    constructor(engine: string);
}
```

Comment: I was getting an error though about requiring `declare `

Comment: Thanks, actually I think I misdirected my test-case, what I have is a definition (`.d.ts`), and I want a constructor on it (`declare module Car {
    constructor(engine: string) {
    }
}`). It's defining an external javascript library.

Comment: Ok, then the implementation should be removed from the constructor, I'll put an example in the answer.

Comment: Hmm, what I am writing interfaces for doesn't take arguments. So I tried `constructor();`, which failed with `TS1036` and `TS2304` errors. Trying with `constructor(void);` fails with `TS1109` error, and trying with `constructor(engine: string);` fails with `TS1005` error. Here is my actual [d.ts](https://github.com/AlecTaylor/waterline_scaffold/blob/master/cust_typings/waterline.d.ts) file. The constructor I am interfacing is [waterline.js#L13](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline.js#L13)

Comment: I've accepted your answer, because I kept extending the question. But if you could reply to my waterline comment that'd be great (and a +1 in it!).