# Angular Material inject to Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular-material

Have problem with add `Angular Material` to my project which is build on `Angular 2`. When project is compiled, return this error :

> initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts

Add `Angular Material` like this :

```
import {MaterialModule } from '@angular/material'
```

And then in `imports`

```
 MaterialModule.forRoot(),
```

Installed by

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

Also installed hammerjs and added into 'angular-cli.json'

```
 "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
```

It's my all `app.module.ts`

```
import {NgModule, NgModuleFactoryLoader, SystemJsNgModuleLoader} from 
'@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import 'hammerjs';

//ui-router
import {UIRouterModule, UIView} from 'ui-router-ng2';
import {APP_STATES} from './app.states';
import {routerConfigFn} from './router.config';

//angular material
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     FormsModule,
     HttpModule,
     MdButtonModule,
     MdCheckboxModule,
     UIRouterModule.forRoot({
        states: APP_STATES,
        useHash: true,
        otherwise: {state: 'public'},
        config: routerConfigFn,
        }),
    ],
    providers: [{provide: NgModuleFactoryLoader, useClass: 
    SystemJsNgModuleLoader}],
    bootstrap: [UIView]
   })

 export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done in code?

Comment: Do you mean app.module.ts ?

Comment: Yes @yazpid app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

There has been significant changes in the latest beta3 (assuming you are using that). It could be related to an error you are having but not sure. You don't import Material Module anymore, instead you import each component individually

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md

```
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
  ...
})
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

Also, no need to import hammerjs via angular/cli just put in in app.modules.ts as an import

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

Comment: I did like above and I have the same problem

Comment: Can you update the OP and show what changes you made and how it looks now?

Comment: Not sure that the error is related to appmodules then. Are you declaring a class somewhere? the error you are having is also related? smth liek this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750702/typescript-constructor-ambient-contexts-error

Comment: This error only occur when I adding angular material. All errors are related to files in @angular/material path

Comment: Files in @angular/material path have `declare` when classes are defined. It could be a problem?

Comment: Doubt it. I am using material myself with angular/cli and I don't experience issues you are having. Perhaps it has something to do with how systemJS works?

Comment: Found this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5693 perhaps your typescript version is out of date? have you tried installing the latest version for angular 2 which if I remember right is 2.0.10 (double check that)

Comment: Cli return erros related to each module from `material`. Like this :ERROR in `node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/overlay/scroll/scroll-dispatcher.d.ts (9,42): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.`

Under this line is code : 

`export declare const DEFAULT_SCROLL_TIME = 20;`

is equal is highlited as error